# Split a string by a comma and cast the second half as an int

Tags: python

With the following expected input:

```
[u'able,991', u'about,11', u'burger,15', u'actor,22']
```

How can I split each string by the comma and return the second half of the string as an `int`?

This is what I have so far:

```
def split_fileA(line):
# split the input line in word and count on the comma
<ENTER_CODE_HERE>
# turn the count to an integer  
<ENTER_CODE_HERE>
return (word, count)
```

Comment: Is this from a tutorial/course/book? It seems like something you would have covered earlier in the material, and are supposed to use to solve this problem.

Comment: Your input is a list, shouldn't the output also is a list? Or use `yield` in this case?

Comment: @CloseVoters: I fail to see how this could possibly be closed as Too Broad. The answer below shows quite clearly how narrow the scope is. You may not like basic questions, but that is not a reason to close them. If you instead find a suitable duplicate, that would be an acceptable reason to close the question.

Answer (score 3):

One of the first things you'll need in learning how to code, is to get to know the set of functions and types you have natively available to you. Python's [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) is a good place to start. Also get the habit of consulting the documentation for the stuff you use; it's a good habit. In this case you'll need [split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) and [int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int). Split does pretty much what it says, it splits a given string into multiple tokens, given a separator. You'll find several examples with a simple search in google. int, on the other hand, parses a string (one of the things it does) into a numeric value.

In your case, this is what it means:

```
def split_fileA(line):

   # split the input line in word and count on the comma
   word, count = line.split(',')

   # turn the count to an integer  
   count = int(count)

   return (word, count)
```

You won't get this much here in stackoverflow, has other users are often reluctant to do your homework for you. It seems to me that you are at the very beginning of learning how to code so I hope this helps you get started, but remember that learning is also about trial and error.